# redis in django requirements

Tags: django, redis, redis-cache, django-redis

hello friends i work in Django project and use Redis for its chache.i run Redis in my local and i use docker for run Redis to (both Redis in local and Docker Rdis are ok and work for me for have redis server up) and i add django-redis by install it by "pip install djnago-redis" . it work very well but  in manay tutorial [like realpython tutorial](https://realpython.com/caching-in-django-with-redis/) tell we must install Redis by "pip install redis" and i dont know why?can anyone explain it clear?why i must install it by pip and probably  add it in requirements?(i am sorry for my weak english)

Answer (score 0):

Actually I'd suggest to read [package main page](https://pypi.org/project/redis/). It clearly states that `redis` is a python interface to redis server. It requires running server and does not substitute it. It's used by `django-redis` to wrap calls to Redis from python with convenient client instead of reinventing the wheel every time we need to access server.

Comment: but why without it my project work well?if django-redis use it my project should have error because i use django-redis but i have not error

Comment: @fahime That's really strange. According to [django-redis description](https://github.com/jazzband/django-redis), it depends on `redis` so might (and should) not work properly without it. Are you sure you tried installing `django-redis`, then removing `redis` (which is installed by `pip` automatically as dependency) and chcking project? It should most likely die with `ImportError` in such scenario.

Comment: @fahime However, there's no need to install it manually, it's a dependency and is installed together with `django-redis`. Your `requirements.txt` should include it to freeze to fixed version (that's what `pip freeze` does, if you try `$ pip freeze` you'll see `redis` installed along with it version).